# get_html_contents not returning source

Tags: php, html

I am  trying to parse the kickass torrent page . But, when I tried to parse it using the get_html_contents, it retuns something which is not understandable. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>
                    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n".
                    "Accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n" .
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6\r\n".
            "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
                )
    ); 
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $html = file_get_html("http://kickass.to/",false,$context);

    echo $html;
?>
```

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
‹í}kwÛ8²àçÎ¯Àh¶'öM ñ-)‰Ýëgâ‰dlwÒ}½™>    IŒ)RÍ‡dgzî9»_öíÇ=ûîýK[zÙ”   ›–      
 2}:3mI$P P¨ …WÚ¿wþó‡ÒOþö“WøA®~oÕúI2|ÑhŒÇãúX¯‡Q¯¡¶ÛíÆ–©×‹¶j~Õ°³Ýí'þ½
°Ä&X“²_So´UÛƒ„  =¿²qÄ¯­ZÂ®’BzIœ¾Å,ÙJ“.mÕw:K®}v+8'Žç«ö€mÕ
\;‘7L¼0˜©qÆìÈé;p•ØIã˜lÌwíQy #çIÜÇ1ùÿÊ"ÅÏÉ ‰Ï4ö^¡xâúwâ%>ÛÞÇÚ.9£PÆurhÇ    
 ¯p1–?'yÁ˜PòÖs.í8Î«¼jX®ï—$bþV-Æ6ˆûŒ%5’@KÌ4éG¬»Uk4Nb'žSwÂAÃö}ÚÕµ¦á°:/•7zM
 ´:iÜÄÑ£ÄIâ9Øp·‚õvÅ h0,T‡?HOáÙÃ!ô[¦NŸÞ r±t}ô8löO”^x]rt@šŸg)
 ¿$0ÜðXs¾îjÇ¼AþtÁ×ë~¦ô&îVYÜ­Špú ¢mçh…\“8rnàýóÑeÖ^0aüK<‡ò‹=²ˆÚö«†øv=³$ÜÅyûá­
>ÃªøÿFvD.í„l‘Lžá?@Àì˜ýâ¹/ÈÓõÓçsE\–0'ùÅ·ƒÞ¢Ì¿‹‡vÄ~q|†/ˆš?ýçKAÄ|-oýÙW¾Ýg†‹Ÿ°
(°–WÅá96ª±FÇÏ®PsõÊ,í ˜#IHNÏÎH—1w2À~€â[jÞ¶‹êqj­{MGêŒrüÙqÞ5¼ZëÌë¾ywpø³•¶5O    
S=Ùa½¿í]jï¯ßÿõx¨ÂÆ¬Cáuì¡ÝñgçÂkO¹¿«: mÓŽQ>,gàt|Û¹¤Id±Ÿ:ðh 5ý™Æ±ùKìü ƒ“üö¹øür"é¯Â^xÕ  Ýkøp½ñÜ­Ú8‚ÇÂã£ àï&ÏVR[Žk°–«µºV·Ó´ºL7X»ã¶£ÝÂÁ…g«èmæ@1×5Ì&3mG×›PÉíªª©(®iMªÌQà‡=´Ñhþ-2Á¢í'ß½ lQnÀ‚(üî»Wv.µ@ˆ•mþÒãÏÐ°xã¹, ÇñÚª]Ú Öè×0Ôï­šúaô‚ü¹ƒ§c¼$]è &_Ù¢Ã+xÖCòÂgÝä%é3¯×O^SÁ7 ûŒÎ=B2#ù#:ˆ{$ÍÔÄw“ÙW 3‡‘„Ã“¸Çû/#¬ûÆ|óÁªuƒjæÜ8áÝÔð½Y,KÁ¯ KüpŒ„#–^|ËRÉ¨4ðó2€¹S_Ò Læ©Ç§28¸‡T„´Eâ½xÃk¬ ƒ¡†—…ðåÀŽ.ì],*{ÆTbbg8”ÃxVº—w°´ø0é³¨Ôx%oË\]]wªaý§Ÿ~ºö«Fêgº){>ý2¯~@©ÒÀK®oÓ@“—KuÐ¤Ô‚BL32÷M†(˜Ó³ýP€b*Ï@ŸcfŠ¢kÿzxZÃáÎßnE¹¥é`Nì7¸=s×t…dÀÄ¿œ‚SÖóbðSHƒœy½€·”uì«Ì,`Œ5rÃIØeÌa atÓdKìžã‡©;¡vòANøÊ,Ui)ÃÆlY£¶ÍŠ¾QASTc±<>+.nÎW^Þ,(¯»s¥õÚ¶î5•ï5%îCÓÄð%ìÂŸ^Ä®çêkµmS!¢   Á‡à@}F ²xC÷ó€òD¼.ÀÌë¹7*‹ÇE•"˜áoTÁ‡: ;Y¤:à5#Åvê/6œ(C°Á÷ p-/ìËÐ¿^„0óª r×xþ5¶|z£áÅ;oŠ*{Ýäúî>BxÉrÝØƒõ%ð¬¨8Š7ÊãÃ¢  ó¹e?O ZP§òœ»¤…»‹ cÙë"@0ÙƒuùÓ‚*}ôÃæj€ËÆUA‡åÔ:väÞ •—@bùÛ08"(:ß·ç’YÛž}WT=±›þ’=1À¡ÆU° ·HsV„L €º„·0È/–oì: OøÛ" hÕìàFåìyA5?yËƒ;ôðK[U‘'ÔH3ÊÉ Óy…Ý¬móªDT$P€–š¨+¬Pˆ2N8 Glpgëïø²ÈuàÚ‹¼ò‡rÃ¾Æ`bßßR%`_ÓE1ÂgEÅýEèA‘ú§Û:†¼qˆr“r¾:–"X† w;(jŠUÞb]þ°¨óÓ^z£ZT¥·82’"i›øÇÿ‚lpýÃÂèz±)á)bQd9H\èòÁ¹A9Ê_.:9îßV¿XZõ‹\ÝVŸ/­PÜ|ñþ†·É­T`Q t9/´ðØöqpÃ7LµÅÑ‰ð²ßK€ÂÙQ1o#p 2Ò@Ù‚gÞ—švàÍàtÍ´$ d8$ø¼ â’Öc²DKaþ Çh14qè|Ó‹¹‹Ê++FšdR¤àµ×½¾a¥âÃ%åó­Æ3¾#Ë,è¬rS+¨‹/xÕÜ²·óB¸8i*`{:|—uF0ÚÂf¢ž‚Ë[{ÙòVØëùìÜîÅ|Á—¾²u³¾ç22õæ|\$mqàµí¿üùJ3wµ—³¾Þ¬ï1°½`£"[y~ò*Áu2öÜ¤¿USå{`æw¨í@_nÕñ{h»îäw¶t¦P_rÜII"î%îDáªõµíiƒ} ¤vcAI,‘éž°Í=º¬8£1¸^Ð(Ðn¸ìúh,pæÀd{@yÓ9vÂz ÅF
```

Comment: You need complete code from that page?

Comment: yes!!I need to get the torrent download links.

Comment: @Testing: Is there a way to do that/

Comment: I have tried all the possible ways to get this but it is gzipped from the server. ;) I am trying. @torrezz

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go, it will work like a charm for you:

```
<?php
    $html = gzdecode(file_get_contents('http://kat.ph'));
    preg_match_all('/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i', $html, $links);
    var_dump($links);
```

Comment: **gzdecode** decodes the gzipped content, and I used **preg_match_all** to check for all the links in the content using **regular expressions**

Comment: Do you think it fulfills the requirements of OP?